# rake task only visible from the command line not from rails console or in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake

I have the following in my rails app in (Rails.root/lib/tasks/me.rake):

```
task :abc do
  puts "here is abc"
end
```

and am able to call:

```
rake abc # works
```

but the following don't work:

```
irb> rake :abc # doesn't work
bash>rake -T # doesn't show up
```

nor:

```
describe 'query task061', task061:true do
  it 'should query' do
    FactoryGirl.create(:location2)
    Q.count.should == 1
    rake['abc'].invoke
  end
end
```

What else do I need to do to allow a task to be called in these ways?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Give a description to task and see if it works, it should be,

```
desc "your task desc"
task :abc do
  puts "here is abc"
end
```